# Add column in PowerBI based on when event occured

Tags: sql, powerbi

I am very new to PowerBI, SQL, and Stack Overflow so sorry in advance if this is something easy or already existing. My Google skills for these systems are not the greatest yet.

I have two tables from two different SQL servers.

In Table One I have data like this (technically there is also an EndTime_Local but I don't see the need for it so I removed it):

```
StartTime_Local     PK                  Activity_FK
7/12/2023 15:51:18  15202000000203119   15202000000158652
7/12/2023 15:50:56  15202000000203118   15202000000158651
7/12/2023 15:50:04  15202000000203117   15202000000158650
7/12/2023 15:49:10  15202000000203116   15202000000158649
7/12/2023 15:48:03  15202000000203115   15202000000158648
7/12/2023 15:46:53  15202000000203114   15202000000158647
7/12/2023 15:46:07  15202000000203113   15202000000158646
7/12/2023 15:42:34  15202000000203112   15202000000158645
7/12/2023 15:42:06  15202000000203111   15202000000158644
7/12/2023 15:41:40  15202000000203110   15202000000158643
```

In Table Two I have data like this:

```
id      Event_Time          Data Stuff
19271   7/12/2023 15:51:53  data stuff
19272   7/12/2023 15:51:53  data stuff
19270   7/12/2023 15:50:19  data stuff
19269   7/12/2023 15:50:18  data stuff
19268   7/12/2023 15:45:54  data stuff
19267   7/12/2023 15:45:43  data stuff
```

In Excel I made a third table to include TableOneActivity_FK with the following formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(MAXIFS(Table_1[StartTime_Local],Table_1[StartTime_Local],"<=" &[@[Event_Time]]),Table_1,3,FALSE)
```

Table Three looks like this:

```
id      Event_Time          Data Stuff  TableOneActivity_FK
19271   7/12/2023 15:51:53  data stuff  15202000000158652
19272   7/12/2023 15:51:53  data stuff  15202000000158652
19270   7/12/2023 15:50:19  data stuff  15202000000158650
19269   7/12/2023 15:50:18  data stuff  15202000000158650
19268   7/12/2023 15:45:54  data stuff  15202000000158645
19267   7/12/2023 15:45:43  data stuff  15202000000158645
```

The purpose of the formula is to determine what the Activity_FK was when the "Event_Time" data occurred. IE the event time in table two occurred at 7/12/2023 15:51 and from 15:51 to 15:52 in table one, my Activity_FK is 15202000000158652.

In PowerBI, how would I display my Activity_FK from table one to be how my TableOneActivity_FK is setup in table three since my Event_Time does not match my StartTime_Local?